# perl script to search for multiple lines from a file with start and end keywords

Tags: perl

I am trying to search in a .sql file for sql statement which starts with CREATE TABLE followed by fields values then keywords [TB_DATA and TB_INDX] and ends by ; it in multiple lines

.sql file statement is in multiple lines

```
-- CREATE TABLE HDTB_COD;
CREATE TABLE HDTB_CODE( IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)

IN TB_DATA INDEX 
IN TB_INDX;

CREATE TABLE HDTB_RES
(ARTID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)
IN TB_DATA INDEX 
IN TB_INDX;
-- DROP TABLE HDTB_COD;
CREATE TABLE HDTB_DE ( IDPK VARCHAR(256) 
NOT NULL);
```

-------------output----------------------

```
CREATE TABLE HDTB_CODE( IDPK VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)

IN TB_DATA INDEX IN TB_INDX;

CREATE TABLE HDTB_RES(ARTID VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL)

IN TB_DATA INDEX IN TB_INDX;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -n -e 'chomp; next if (/^--/);@p=() if /CREATE TABLE/; push @p,$_; if (/IN TB_DATA INDEX IN TB_INDX;/) { print "@p\n"; }' t.sql
```

How it works

```
chomp; # remove newlines
next if (/^--/);  #skip lines that are SQL comments
@p = () if /CREATE TABLE/; #start of a table definition, clear array @p
push @p, $_; # put current line into array @p
#condition found, print @p    
if (/IN TB_DATA INDEX IN TB_INDX;/) { print "@p\n"; }
```

Comment: how to check in a perl script
i want it to store only from CREATE TABLE till ; semicolon
like if (/CREATE TABLE/) till (/;/) into a separate file

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are asking Vivek?

Comment: .sql file will have data in multiple lines

open my $fh, "</home/svn/mqsc/dbtype.sql" or die $!;

chomp ($fh);
print $fh;
next if (/^--/);
@p=() if /CREATE TABLE/;
push @p,$_;
if (/.*;/) # how to end at semicolen, there may be a comment after it.  { print "@p\n"; }

Comment: ``s/(?!;)\s*--.*$//;`` add that before the ``push``

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create quick-and-dirty parsing pipelines. Once you understand the basic pattern, it's easy to add more filtering steps (with `grep`) or transforming steps (with `map`)

```
# Slurp entire file.
my $sql = do { local $/ = undef; <> };

# 1. Grab the CREATE TABLE statements.
# 2. Retain only the statements of interest.
# 3. Modify the statements as needed before printing.
print
    map  { "$_\n" }                         # 3b. Add trailing newlines.
    map  { s/\s+/ /g; $_ }                  # 3a. Normalize whitespace.
    grep { /IN TB_INDX/ }                   # 2b. Filter.
    grep { /IN TB_DATA INDEX/ }             # 2a. Filter.
    $sql =~ /^(CREATE TABLE .+?;)\s*$/gsm;  # 1.  Grab.
```